# scheduling tasks in linux

Tags: c, linux

Can we schedule a program to execute every 5 ms or 10 ms etc?
I need to generate a pulse through the serial port for 1 khz and 15 khz. 
But the program should only toggle the pins in the serial port , so the frequency has to be produced by a scheduler. is this possible in linux with a rt patch?

Comment: I doubt it. Have you considered using threads?

Comment: no, I have never used threads. but shouldn't this be possible in rt linux, after all that is its use, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a better solution is to put your "generate a pulse" function in a loop, for example:

```
for (;;) {
    generate_pulse(); /* generate a pulse */
    sleep(5ms);       /* or 10ms */
}
```

Comment: ya, thats working, I have tried it, but I want to test the scheduling capability of my kernel.

Comment: @aash But launching a program every 5ms or 10ms, you are actually testing the cache and/or disk device read capabilities, instead of kernel's scheduling capability.

Comment: but if i am going to assign a priority to both the tasks and schedule them to run at the same time, then i can check if the the task with a higher priority is running or not.

Comment: @aash I do not believe that your choose way is proper for what you want to test.

Comment: can you please suggest a better way?

Comment: @aash Sorry, I am not familiar with real time development, you should ask other people, or ask a more specific question in which clearly state your real time environment and your intention.

Answer (score 1):

`is this possible in linux with a rt patch?`

I suggest to go for RT patch, if timing is critical.

[Xenomai](http://www.xenomai.org/) is a RT patch which I used on 2.6 kernel some days back.

Here is an example which runs every 1 second.
http://www.xenomai.org/documentation/trunk/html/api/trivial-periodic_8c-example.html

Comment: I already have a rt patch downloaded from kernel.org, and patched with my 3.0 kernel. can i use xenomai with 3.x kernel and is it better than the patches from kernel.org?

Comment: @aash Latest xenomai version 2.6.3 may work for 3.4 and 3.5 kernels. But I never tested.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [PPS project](http://linuxpps.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) that is now part ( at least a portion of it for the 2.6 branch, but in the latest 3.x kernel branch it looks like there is a full integration ) of the [mainline linux kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/pps/pps.txt).

There is also an explicit reference to using this PPS implementation with a serial port in the linked txt file

> A PPS source can be connected to a **serial port** (usually to the Data
>   Carrier Detect pin) or to a parallel port (ACK-pin) or to a special
>   CPU's GPIOs (this is the common case in embedded systems) but in each
>   case when a new pulse arrives the system must apply to it a timestamp
>   and record it for userland.

Apparently good examples / tutorials / guides, are not even [that hard to find](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.time.nuts/32276) , I'm sure that you'll find a lot of good resources while just using search engine.

The header for the APIs is usually under `/usr/include/linux/pps.h` .

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a way to get it done.
The best way to do it is to first create a timer with the required amount of time. and then to call the task( which is the pulse generating program) every time the timer overflows. The program for the timer can be run in the background. the timer can be created and set using the timer_create() and timer_settime() respectively. A different program can be called from one program using fork() and execl(). The program can be run in the background using the daemon(). 
By using all these things we can create our own scheduler.